# log4j red message in my java execution

Tags: java, log4j

When I run a easy main java class I have this red messages:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 3 and column 83
log4j:WARN Attribute "status" must be declared for element type "log4j:configuration".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 31 and column 23
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "(renderer*,throwableRenderer?,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)".
```

Should I a log4j configuration via a log4j.xml file?

**My log4j file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' status="INFO">

    <appender name="consoleDebug" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
          value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %-5p %c{1}:%l]: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="consoleInfo" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
          value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="org.openqa.selenium">  
        <priority value="off" />  
    </category>
    <category name="org.apache.log4j">  
        <priority value="off" />  
    </category>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleInfo" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: post your log4j.xml

Comment: It looks like it is already loading a log4j configuration file from somewhere and it has some errors in it

Comment: I had my log4j file in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `status="INFO"` attribute from this line:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' status="INFO">
```

The error says that this attribute is not declared in DTD, thus making the XML non-valid.

The error message originates from the XML parser, and it suggests to declare the attribute in `log4j.dtd`. Of course, it doesn't make sense to change the DTD in this case, so just remove the `status` attribute from the `<log4j:configuration>` element.

Comment: delete status="INFO" solve a problem and put <root> after <category> solve the other problem